# Asp.Net MVC - Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm looking at Haacks article here - http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/31/single-project-areas.aspx

When I download the sample I get the following errors in the Global.ascx

> Error 1   'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'MapAreaRoute' and no extension method
>   'MapAreaRoute' accepting a first
>   argument of type
>   'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I assume I am obviously missing somthing, anyone any ideas what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should now use "AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas" in the new implementation

This blog post may be of use to you:

http://suhair.in/Blog/aspnet-areas-in-depth

Snippets of code from the blog:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); 1
     RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

plus...

```
public static void RegisterAllAreas() 
{
      RegisterAllAreas(null);
}

public static void RegisterAllAreas(object state) 
{
                                 2                        3
      RegisterAllAreas(RouteTable.Routes, new BuildManagerWrapper(), state);
}
```